# How to check if there is an intersection of multiple ranges?

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of ranges like [[s1,t1], [s2,t2], ...] where each element of the array is a range from si to ti for all i's, and they are well formed that is si<=ti, how can I check if there is an intersection between all ranges?

EDIT:

The requirement is to check if there is a common overlap of ALL ranges at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: If every `si` is smaller or equal than the smallest `ti`, all ranges intersect.

Comment: if si<=ti and when you mean intersection, do you mean the value of si and ti are equal ?

Comment: For example given  [[3, 8], [4,9], [5,10]], there is a common intersection, because it is [5,8].

Comment: another example [[3,5], [6,9]], there is no common intersection.

Comment: `[[3, 8], [4,9], [5,10]].every((r, i, arr) => r[0] <= Math.min(...arr.map(r => r[1])));` is `true`. `[[3,5], [6,9]].every((r, i, arr) => r[0] <= Math.min(...arr.map(r => r[1])))` is `false`.

Comment: How does it look if it was not es6 lol?

Comment: The same, just use function expressions and call `Math.min.apply`. The logic is the same.

Comment: What's `every` and `...arr` ?

Comment: `common overlap of ALL ranges at the same time` you mean like this `[[1-5], [3-5], [4-5]]` where common overlapping elements are `4` and `5`

Comment: [Spread Operator ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Your example is right, (4,5) is common overlap of all ranges. And how would I use it but not using es6. Can you show example code?

Comment: `every`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every . `foo(...arr)` is the same as `foo.apply(null, arr)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer:

1. Sort the ranges by si
2. In the sorted list, count the number of times where si < t(i-1) - This is the number of intersections.

---

```
var ranges = [[7, 11], [2, 5], [1, 3], [5, 8]], intersections = 0, i = 0;
ranges.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[0] < a[0];
});
for(i=1; i<ranges.length; i++) {
  if(ranges[i][0] < ranges[i-1][1]) {
    intersections++;
  }
}
console.log('Intersections:', intersections); // Outputs "Intersections: 2"
```

Comment: I understood that the OP wants to check whether there is an intersection between *all* ranges. Your solution, I believe counts the number of intersection between any two ranges, is that correct? The OP should certainly clarify what they want...

Comment: The requirement is to check if there is a common overlap of ALL ranges at the same time.

Comment: Ah. Ok. I kind of didn't understand that at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is I way I think could work. Anyone know if I am missing anything?

Thanks

```
function hasOverlap(ranges) {
    if (ranges.length > 0) {
        ranges = ranges.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
            if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
            return 0;
        });

        var min_r = ranges[0][0];
        var max_r = ranges[0][1];
        for(var i=1; i<ranges.length; i+=1) {
            if (ranges[i][0] > max_r) {
                return false;
            }
            min_r = Math.max(min_r, ranges[i][0]);
            max_r = Math.min(max_r, ranges[i][1]);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, one solution would be to check whether each `si` is smaller than or equal to the smallest `ti`.

```js
function overlaps(ranges) {
  var minT = Math.min.apply(Math, ranges.map(function(r) { return r[1]; }));
  return ranges.every(function(r) { return r[0] <= minT; });
}

console.log(overlaps([[3,8], [4,9], [5,10]]));
console.log(overlaps([[3,5], [6,9]]));
console.log(overlaps([[1,5], [3,5], [4,5]]));
```